# Relationship between parent and child modules in Dojo

Tags: dojo

I've defined a custom Dojo module as follows:

```
 define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
], function (declare, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetBase,_WidgetsInTemplateMixin){
    var _Base = declare("tt.widget.dashboards._Base", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

    widgetsInTemplate: true,
    .....
    });
    return _Base;
}
```

I've also defined another module which extends the `_Base.js` module as shown below:
**Definition 1**

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/text!tt/widget/landingPages/templates/InviteeWelcome.html",
    "dojo/topic",
    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "tt/widget/RoundedBox",
    "t/widget/RoundedButton",
    "tt/widget/Dashboards/_Base"
], function (declare, template, topic, CheckBox, RoundedBox, RoundedButton, _Base) {

    var InviteeWelcome = declare("tt.widget.landingPages.InviteeWelcome", _Base,
{
 ...
});
```

**Definition 2**

```
define([
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/text!tt/widget/landingPages/templates/InviteeWelcome.html",
        "dojo/topic",
        "dijit/form/CheckBox",
        "tt/widget/RoundedBox",
        "t/widget/RoundedButton",
            "dijit/_WidgetBase",
            "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
            "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
        "tt/widget/Dashboards/_Base"
    ], function (declare, template, topic, CheckBox, RoundedBox, RoundedButton, _Base, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin) {

        var InviteeWelcome = declare("tt.widget.landingPages.InviteeWelcome", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _Base],
    {
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        ...
    });
```

My question is that which one of above will be the correct definition of `InviteeWelcome.js`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In definition 1 you're using the following hierarchy:

```
_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin => _Base => InviteeWelcome
```

While in your second definition you're using the following hierarchy:

```
_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin => _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _Base => InviteeWelcome
```

In this case there is no difference at all (except maybe performance related). `_Base` is already inheriting from both `_WidgetBase`, `_TemplatedMixin` and `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`, so if you inherit from those 3 + `_Base`, then `_Base` will "override" them all (because it already has al the behavior of the other modules).

But if you would change the order of mixin modules in definition 2so that it becomes:

```js
[ _Base, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ]
```

Then everything you override in `_Base`, will be overridden again by their defaults in `_WidgetBase`, `_TemplatedMixin` and `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`.

I think your first approach will work as well and may be less confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much. You explanation was very nice and helpful to me. Accepting your answer.

Comment: I've posted a question related to Dojo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195535/how-to-migrate-dojo-connect-code-from-dojo-1-3-1-to-1-9-3) Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a question here?

The differences between **Definition 1** and **Definition 2** is only that in `Def 1` you don't have _WidgetsInTemplateMixin added. The two custom modules you have both extend the same _Base class, however in `Def 2` you add the same mixins twice. The only consequence, is that you classes are applied from left to right, so you could inadvertendly overwrite some setting. (Although this wouldn't be the case from the example you have provided).

Also, moving forward with dojo, it's better to avoid the module names if you don't need them.

Here is a mini custom module that I recently created this morning..

```
define( [
    "dojo/text!./TemplatePalette.html",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom-construct",  
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/topic"

    ] ,
    function( template, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, declare, 
              domConstruct, lang, topic ){    
        return declare( [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin ], { 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    });
```

Comment: Actually I'm a newbie to Dojo and these classes were written by someone else. So, I just wanted to confirm that If I include _Base in `InviteeWelcome.js`, do I need to explicitly include `_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin`? because they are already included in `_Base.js`