# How to migrate dojo.connect code from Dojo 1.3.1 to 1.9.3

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've following piece of code in my application which is written in **Dojo 1.3.1**. My task if to migrate this code to **Dojo 1.9.3**. My questions is that how I can achieve this? I'm a newbie to Dojo so don't know much about migration from old Dojo syntax to new.

```
dialogWidget._proxyConnects.push(dojo.connect(
        newDialog._fadeIn,
        "onEnd",
        dialogWidget,
        "onLoad"
       ));
```

**EDIT**
I would also like to know that what the above piece of code will do actually? If anyone can explain this to me in one or two sentences.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This part](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/migration-2.0#events) of Dojo migration guide should help you out.

As on what this does -- you're pushing a (Dojo) connect even handler, that  would execute an `onLoad` method of `dialogWidget` after `newDialog._fadeIn` fires `onEnd` event. What for -- I can't really say, since I don't know the context this one is run in. Also since it accesses private property of `dialogWidget`, I wouldn't be surprised that this would break during update.

Hope this helps.