# dojo.connect(obj, event, context, method, dontFix); to dojo on amd 1.9

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have code snippet available written in dojo  1.3.

```
dialogWidget._proxyConnects.push(dojo.connect(
        newDialog._fadeIn,
        "onEnd",
    dialogWidget,
    "onLoad"
));.
```

When I write on instead of the dojo.connect (After requiring the dojo/on) gives me the error `target unspecified` Can any one help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the [answer to similar question you made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195535/how-to-migrate-dojo-connect-code-from-dojo-1-3-1-to-1-9-3), this might either because of an update or because your code accesses a private property that doesn't exist anymore.

Try to understand what exactly that piece of code was supposed to do, and act accordingly.